# Injecting packages installed from source into apt/synaptic

Tags: software-installation, synaptic, sox

Example:

I build/install `SoX` myself, as provided Ubuntu package did not include additional audio format libraries that I might use and it's one of the packages I want latest version anyway.

Now I want to install `eboard` with Synaptic, and it wants to install `SoX`, but as mentioned `SoX` is already installed and working perfectly and I don't want to mess it with another install while I want to install `eboard` without building it from source.

This is example to problem I faced couple of times and thought to ask what Linux users do in such cases as I'm a new user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you install checkinstall from the repo's

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

then when you install from source instead of doing

```
sudo make install
```

if you run instead

```
sudo checkinstall
```

it will create a package and have a record of it in synaptic/apt and as long as the version numbers are correct it should satisfy the dependencies

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dave :) I got another tip about `equivs` http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/howto/linux/equivs.htm on Debian forum, but using `checkinstall` was piece of cake. Rebuilded it successfully, and Synaptic recognise it as present.